# ImageView next to TextView in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

How do I get an ImageView next to a TextView in a Linearlayout?

**Like this:**

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.75" />
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"

    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it not better to add android:layout_weight="1.0" in the root LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try `drawableRight` attribute in TextView Also..

Answer (score 0):

You can set horizontal orientation to linear layout and weights for both of your views.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation into your vertical LinearLayout :

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
        <ImageView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Others layout here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to add some attributes into TextView and ImageView.

Comment: I ofcourse did. I was missing the android:layout_weight part. See answer Gooziec.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```